# 'constexpr' non-static member function will not be implicitly 'const' in C++1y; add 'const' to avoid a change in behavior

Tags: c++, constants, clang, constexpr

clang++ give the following warning(see code below):

> 'constexpr' non-static member function will not be implicitly 'const'
>   in C++1y; add 'const' to avoid a change in behavior

Where should the `const` be add so? `const constexpr size_t getSize() {` give another warning:

> 'const' type qualifier on return type has no effect

code:

```
constexpr size_t getSize()
{
    return sizeof(header);
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe it's telling you that *the member function can't be called on a `const` object as of C++1y*.

Add `const` after `getSize()` to make it a `const` member function:

```
constexpr size_t getsize() const { ... }
```

Comment: Incidentally, here's a post that explains the C++1y change: http://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2013/06/20/constexpr-function-is-not-const/

Answer (score 1):

Complete testcase:

```
struct S {
  constexpr int getSize();
};
```

Diagnostic:

```
tmp.cc:2:17: warning: 'constexpr' non-static member function will not be
        implicitly 'const' in C++1y; add 'const' to avoid a change in
        behavior [-Wconstexpr-not-const]
  constexpr int getSize();
                ^
                          const
```

Note in particular the bottom line of the output. That's called a 'fix-it hint' and shows you the text you need to insert (and where to insert it) to fix the problem.

(In this case, the text starts with a leading space, making it slightly less clear that it should be inserted before the semicolon, not afterwards.)